# Generate Network Graph in Python from nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I have an input dictionary like:

```
d={'node1':{'node1_1':1.2,'node1_2':1.3,'node1_3':1.2},'node2': 
           {'node2_1':1.3,'node2_2':1.3,'node2_3':1.4}}
```

In the output, node1 has a relationship with node1_1 with a weight of 1.2, node1_2 with a weight of 1.3, and node 1-3 with a weight of 1.2. The same is the case for node2 it links with node 2_1,node2_2, and node2_3 along with their respective weights.
Is there any generalized way to generate a directed graph from the input dictionary using NetworkKx or through any other way in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`nx.from_dict_of_lists`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_dict_of_lists.html):

```
d={'node1':{'node1_1':1.2,'node1_2':1.3,'node1_3':1.2},
   'node2':{'node2_1':1.3,'node2_2':1.3,'node2_3':1.4}}

import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_dict_of_lists(d, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
```

To have the weights, use [`nx.from_dict_of_dicts`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_dict_of_dicts.html):

```
d2 = {k:{k2: {'weight': v2} for k2,v2 in v.items()} for k,v in d.items()}
G = nx.from_dict_of_dicts(d2, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
```

output:

[image: nextworkx graph]

Comment: weights on edges are not shown on the graph on my end. I have run the second one in code snippets.

Comment: @NoorulainIslam the weights are defined: check `nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')`

Comment: after running the nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight'). I have got this output {('node1', 'node1_1'): 1.2,
 ('node1', 'node1_2'): 1.3,
 ('node1', 'node1_3'): 1.2,
 ('node2', 'node2_1'): 1.3,
 ('node2', 'node2_2'): 1.3,
 ('node2', 'node2_3'): 1.4} however, the graph is not shown. Can you please tell me how can I show this graph on my end?

Comment: @NoorulainIslam I see, I used a custom code to display the graph, You won't get a display with the above commands, just a graph object. You should read the [`networkx` drawing](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html) documentation as this is out of the scope of this question (short tip, try `nx.draw(G)` for a basic graph)